Can this improper real integral be solved without complex numbers?
I'm taking a complex variables course, and we had this question on a homework:
$$\int_0^\infty \dfrac{x \sin(2 x)}{x^2 + 3} dx$$
I know how to solve this, but I was curious if this can possibly be solved without relying in any way on complex numbers (no approximations).

Maybe use integration by parts? Just a guess.

It is so simple with complex numbers to have the antiderivative and the definite integral.

The integral can be approached via the Laplace Transform.
We firstly make the substitution $x\to\sqrt 3x\iff \mathrm dx\to\sqrt 3\,\mathrm dx$ and get
$$\int_0^\infty\dfrac{x\sin(2x)}{x^2+3}\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^\infty\dfrac{x\sin(2\sqrt 3x)}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm dx$$
Now let's consider the parametric integral
$$I(\alpha)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(\alpha x)}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm dx$$
If we apply the Laplace Transform to it with respect to $\alpha$ we'd get
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathcal L[I(\alpha)](s)&=\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha s}\left(\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(\alpha x)}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm dx\right)\,\mathrm d\alpha\\
&=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-\alpha s}\cos(\alpha x)}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm d\alpha\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^2+1}\left[\frac{e^{-\alpha s}(x\sin(\alpha x)-s\cos(\alpha x))}{s^2+x^2}\right|_0^\infty\mathrm dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{s}{(x^2+1)(s^2+x^2)}\mathrm dx\\
&=-s\left[\frac{s\tan^{-1}(x)-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{s(1-s^2)}\right|_0^\infty=\frac{\pi}{2(s+1)}
\end{aligned}$$
This means
$$\mathcal L[I(\alpha)](s)=\frac{\pi}{2(s+1)}\iff I(\alpha)=\mathcal L^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi}{2(s+1)}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-\alpha},$$
wherein the last result can be found in any LT tables in any book of reference.
Finally, if we differentiate both sides with respect to $\alpha$, multiply by a negative sign and evaluate at $\alpha=2\sqrt 3$, we'll retrieve the original integral:
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x\sin(2\sqrt 3 x)}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm dx=-\left.\frac{\mathrm d I(\alpha)}{\mathrm d\alpha}\right|_{\alpha=2\sqrt 3}=\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-2\sqrt 3}$$
In brief,
$$\boxed{\int_0^\infty\dfrac{x\sin(2x)}{x^2+3}\,\mathrm dx=\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-2\sqrt 3}}$$
